# How to select/filter rows in MS Excel based on cell value

Tags: excel, row, filtering

I'm working on an excel sheet which has a simple structure like this.

```
 Date          |  Order
 -----------------------
 08-15-2014    |  84
 08-16-2014    |  50
 08-17-2014    |  68
 08-17-2014    |  78
 08-18-2014    |  23
```

Here, in a separate column I'd like to calculate the sum of Orders by week days(Sunday, Monday and so on). Meaning, I want to see how many Orders received on Sunday, Monday etc.

So far I have come up with this non working formula.

```
=SUM(LOOKUP(1, WEEKDAY(date_column), order_column))
```

This was example for summing all order received on Sunday. And, yes Date column is in DateTime Data type so that shouldn't be a problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using a **Pivot Table**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding a new column after the dates, representing the day values. So in column B you might have something like `=TEXT(WEEKDAY(A2),"ddd")`.

Then if you wanted to sum up order numbers by day, you could use an equation like `=SUMIF(B1:B5,"Sun",C1:C5)` where column B has the day values and column C has the order numbers.

To show an example (with headers, etc):

[image]

Comment: This looks easy enough. Thanks a ton.